# Filter not working in Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, function, filter

I'm trying to filter the elements of a list by quantity using Qt. It's just that I press the filter button and nothing happens. Maybe i'm doing something wrong in the SLOT function. The filter function that I'm using works perfectly in my other program where I'm not using Qt. This is how the windows look like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUDte.png `- I uploaded the picture with the windows on imgur because I don't have 10 reputation to upload it from here.`

```
void MedicineManagementGUI::openFilterWindow(){
    ui.filterWindow = new QWidget;
    uiFilterMedicine.setupUI(ui.filterWindow);
    QObject::connect(uiFilterMedicine.btnFilterQuantity,SIGNAL(clicked()),uiFilterMedicine.filterWindow,SLOT(filterAllByQuantity()));
    ui.filterWindow->show();
}
```

the filter SLOT

```
void MedicineManagementGUI::filterAllByQuantity(){
    uiFilterMedicine.medFilterList->clear();
    QString quantityQString = uiFilterMedicine.txtQuantity->text();
    int quantity = quantityQString.toInt();
    List<Medicine*> filtered = ctrl->filterByLessQuantity(quantity);
    for(int i=0; i < filtered.size(); i++){
        int ID = filtered.getElement(i)->getID();
        string name = filtered.getElement(i)->getName();
        float concentration = filtered.getElement(i)->getConcentration();
        int quantity = filtered.getElement(i)->getQuantity();

        QString iDQString = QString::number(ID);
        QString nameQString = QString::fromStdString(name);
        QString concentrationQString = QString::number(concentration);
        QString quantityQString = QString::number(quantity);

        QString medicineAsString = iDQString+" - "+nameQString+" - "+concentrationQString+" - "+quantityQString;
        QListWidgetItem* item = new QListWidgetItem(medicineAsString, uiFilterMedicine.medFilterList);
        item->setData(Qt::UserRole,iDQString);
    }
}
```

the filter function:
 The class:

```
class Filter{
public:
    virtual bool include(Medicine* m)=0;
    virtual ~Filter(){};
};

class LessThanQuantity: public Filter{
private:
    int quantity;
public:
    LessThanQuantity(int q){
        this->quantity=q;
    }
    bool include(Medicine* m){
        return m->getQuantity()<quantity;
    }
};
```

the filter functions from controller:

```
List<Medicine*> Controller::filterBy(Filter* filter){
    List<Medicine*> rez = List<Medicine*>();
    List<Medicine*> medList = repo->getAll();
    Iterator<Medicine*> it = medList.getIterator();
    for(it.first(); it.valid(); it.urmator()){
        Medicine* m = it.element();
        if(filter->include(m)){
            rez.insert(rez.size(),m);
        }
    }
    return rez;
}

List<Medicine*> Controller::filterByLessQuantity(int quantity){
    LessThanQuantity* f = new LessThanQuantity(quantity);
    return filterBy(f);
}
```

Where am I doing wrong? If you need more information just tell me. :)

Answer (score 0):

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/debug.html

I would add in

```
#include <QDebug>

// ...

// at the top of each function that might not get called
qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO;
```

That should answer your question about if your slot is getting called.  Also the console can print out runtime errors such as if a `QObject::connect` call failed, and things like that.

EDIT: Also I would print out any key metrics that could affect entrance into your loops, such as...

```
List<Medicine*> filtered = ctrl->filterByLessQuantity(quantity);
// this line added before the loop
qDebug() << "filtered.size()" << filtered.size();
```

If the size printed out is zero, then add some debug statements in your `filterByLessQuantity` function and see where you are losing your elements.

Hope that helps.

Comment: phyatt Thanks, I found something! Object::connect: No such slot QWidget::filterAllByQuantity() in ui/medicinemanagementgui.cpp:62. I don't understand why it doesn't recongnizes the filterAllByQuantity() slot. It is a "private slot". I don't get it. :(

Comment: phyatt Funny thing! It recognises the filterAllByQuantity() slot in the connectSignalsToSlots() function but only in several places. Isn't it weird?

Comment: If I call the filterAllByQuantity() slot here `    QObject::connect(ui.btnAdd,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(openWindowToAddMedicine()));` it appers. :(

Comment: phyatt Solved it! :D `QObject::connect(uiFilterMedicine.btnFilterQuantity,SIGNAL(clicked()),uiFilterMedicine.filterWindow,SLOT(filterAllByQuantity()));` instead of `uiFilterMedicine.filterWindow` should be `this` but I put `uiFilterMedicine.filterWindow` because I thought the filterWindow is affected. :) If it weren't for your advices I wouldn't have discovered that. :) Thank you again!